# pip install library with pyd-files on Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, pip, windows-10, sftp, paramiko

When pip-installing the SFTP-lib paramiko I get multiple pyd-files and that don't work with my Google App Engine-dev_appserver.

I should be able to puzzle together a solution free from pyd, but I love how I can just delete and reinstall libraries with pip. I don't want to lose that. What options do I have?